# AD B2C Sign in fails after email invitation sign up

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I followed the [SignUp with email invitation](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite#signup-with-email-invitation) tutorial and it's working fine with one exception. **After the user has completed the sign-up process and is redirected, the application fails to authenticate the user and shows an error.**

Looking at the `OnMessageReceived` event from `OpenIdConnectEvents` reveals that the `MessageReceivedContext.ProtocolMessage.IdToken` is null.

[image: Debug OnMessageReceived event]

However, the user is redirected to */MicrosoftIdentity/Account/Error* with an **id_token** that seems valid.

[image]

On the `OnRemoteFailure` event, I can catch the following error:

```json
{
    "ClassName": "System.Exception",
    "Message": "OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty.",
    "Data": null,
    "InnerException": null,
    "HelpURL": null,
    "StackTraceString": null,
    "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
    "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
    "ExceptionMethod": null,
    "HResult": -2146233088,
    "Source": null,
    "WatsonBuckets": null
}
```

By the way, the new user is correctly added to the AD B2C and is able to sign in afterwards. It's just the sign-up process initiated by the e-mail link that fails to authenticate.

Here's the complete `SignUpInvitation.xml` custom policy:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TrustFrameworkPolicy
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06"
  PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0"
  TenantId="mytenant.onmicrosoft.com"
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_signup_invitation"
  PublicPolicyUri="http://mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_invitation"
  DeploymentMode="Development"
  UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint="urn:journeyrecorder:applicationinsights">

  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>mytenant.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>

  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <!-- Sample: Read only email address to present to the user-->
      <ClaimType Id="ReadOnlyEmail">
        <DisplayName>Verified Email Address</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
    
      <!--Sample: Stores the error message for unsolicited request (a request without id_token_hint) and user not found-->
      <ClaimType Id="errorMessage">
          <DisplayName>Error</DisplayName>
          <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Add help text here</UserHelpText>
          <UserInputType>Paragraph</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType> 
    </ClaimsSchema>

    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <!--Sample: Initiates the errorMessage claims type with the error message-->
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateUnsolicitedErrorMessage" TransformationMethod="CreateStringClaim">
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="value" DataType="string" Value="You cannot sign-up without invitation" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="errorMessage" TransformationClaimType="createdClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>

      <!--Sample: Copy the email to ReadOnlyEmail claim type-->
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="CopyEmailAddress" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ReadOnlyEmail" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>
  </BuildingBlocks>  

  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <!--Sample: Sign-up self-asserted technical profile-->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail">
          <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
            <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
            <!-- Sample: Remove sign-up email verification -->
            <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">False</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <!--Sample: Copy the email to ReadOnlyEamil claim type-->
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CopyEmailAddress" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <!--Sample: Set input the ReadOnlyEmail claim type to prefilled the email address-->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ReadOnlyEmail" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <!-- Sample: Display the ReadOnlyEmail claim type (instead of email claim type)-->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ReadOnlyEmail" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />

            <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <!-- Sample: Disable session management for sign-up page -->
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>      
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Self Asserted</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <!-- Demo: Show error message-->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Unsolicited">
          <DisplayName>Unsolicited error message</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
            <!-- Sample: Remove the continue button-->
            <Item Key="setting.showContinueButton">false</Item>
         </Metadata>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUnsolicitedErrorMessage" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>         
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="errorMessage"/>
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="errorMessage"/>
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <!--Sample: This technical profile specifies how B2C should validate your token, and what claims you want B2C to extract from the token. 
      The METADATA value in the TechnicalProfile meta-data is required. 
      The “IdTokenAudience” and “issuer” arguments are optional (see later section)-->
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>My ID Token Hint ClaimsProvider</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims">
          <DisplayName>My ID Token Hint TechnicalProfile</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="None" />
          <Metadata>
          
            <!--Sample action required: replace with your endpoint location -->
            <Item Key="METADATA">https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1A_SIGNUP_INVITATION</Item>

            <!-- <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">your_optional_audience_override</Item> -->
            <Item Key="issuer">https://localhost:44316/</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!--Sample: Read the email claim from the id_token_hint-->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />  
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>

  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="SignUpInvitation">
        <OrchestrationSteps>

        <!--Sample: Read the input claims from the id_token_hint-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="GetClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims" />

        <!-- Sample: Check if user tries to run the policy without invitation -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                    <Value>email</Value>
                    <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
            </Preconditions>        
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Unsolicited" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Unsolicited"/>
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Sample: Self-asserted sign-up page -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail"/>
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!--Sample: Issue an access token-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer"/>

        </OrchestrationSteps>
        <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb"/>
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>

  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpInvitation" />
    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
        <JourneyInsights TelemetryEngine="ApplicationInsights" InstrumentationKey="64729310-c74e-45ab-a59e-f35f7ada76ee" DeveloperMode="true" ClientEnabled="false" ServerEnabled="true" TelemetryVersion="1.0.0" />
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />

        <!--Sample: Set the input claims to be read from the id_token_hint-->
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="surname" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="givenName" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="displayName"/>
      </InputClaims>
      
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>

</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

## Edit

As mentioned, the invitation link shall redirect to my web app so I added the following route to handle the `id_token_hint`.

```cs
[HttpGet("/redeem/{scheme?}")]
public IActionResult Redeem([FromRoute] string scheme, [Bind(Prefix = "id_token_hint")] string idTokenHint, string policy)
{
    scheme ??= OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    string redirectUrl = Url.Content("~/");

    AuthenticationProperties properties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = redirectUrl,
        Items =
        {
            ["id_token_hint"] = idTokenHint,
            ["policy"] = policy
        }
    };

    return Challenge(properties, scheme);
}
```

In `StartUp.cs`, I had to add the following block to make it work properly.

```cs
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, Constants.AzureAdB2C);

services.Configure<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Events ??= new OpenIdConnectEvents();

    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider += async ctx =>
    {
        // Append token hint when present (ie. email invitation)
        if (ctx.Properties.Items.ContainsKey("id_token_hint"))
            ctx.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = ctx.Properties.Items["id_token_hint"];

        await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using this in your Production Application

The authentication libraries create a `state` when the authentication flow begins from your application. This sample creates a raw link to the Azure AD B2C Policy, also referred to as a "Run Now" link. This type of link is not suitable for your production application instance and should only be used to test the sample.

For a Production scenario, the link containing the the `id_token_hint` should point to your application, `https://myapp.com/redeem?hint=<id_token_hint value>`. The application should have a valid route to handle a query parameter contatining the `id_token_hint`. The App should then use the authentication library to start an authentication to the AAD B2C Policy Id for which this `id_token_hint` is due to be consumed at. The library will contain a method to add query parameters to the authentication request. See the docuementation for the library in use to implement this.

The authentication library will then build the final authentication link, with the `id_token_hint` appended as part of a query parameter. This will now be a valid authentication request and your user will be redirected to the Azure AD B2C policy from your Application. Your application will be able to handle the response from Azure AD B2C properly.

For Single Page Applications, see the documenation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-spa-app-options#pass-id-token-hint).
For .Net Applications, see the documenation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application-options#pass-id-token-hint).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it actually helped me to understand the flow. I edited my question to add some more insights into the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same challenge, the trick was to ensure that my web app had a valid route to handle a query parameter containing the id_token_hint.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace TMF.MagicLinks.WebApp.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class MagicLinksController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public MagicLinksController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        [HttpGet("signin-oidc-link")]
        public IActionResult SignInLink([FromQuery] string id_token_hint)
        {
            var magic_link_auth = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" };
            magic_link_auth.Items.Add("id_token_hint", id_token_hint);

            string magic_link_policy = _configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2CConfiguration")["MagicLinksPolicyId"];
            return Challenge(magic_link_auth, magic_link_policy);
        }
    }
 }
```

You can find the code for the API and the ASPNET web app [here](https://github.com/idaceappdev/sign-in-with-magic-link).